# Reduce code redundancy when conditionally loading Reactjs components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to load different React components inside a parent-like component `<Block1>`.

What I want to achieve is that when I press on the **"next"** button `<Button1>`, `<Component2>` must load inside `<Block1>` and the **"next"** button should change to **"previous"**, but clicking on **"previous"** `<Button2>` must load `<Component1>`.

I don't want to use `<Block2>`. As you can see, I am writing lot of redundant code here. Is there a way to change the components inside `<Block1>` only on button click?

```
var Block1 = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="block">
        <Component1/>
        <Button1/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Component1 = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <p className = "component1">This is Component1</p>
    )
  }
});

var Button1 = React.createClass({
  next: function(){
    ReactDOM.render(<Block2/>, document.getElementById("container"));
  },

  render: function(){
    return(
      <button className = "button1" onClick = {this.next}>Next</button>
    )
  }
});

var Block2 = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="block">
      <Component2/>
      <Button2/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Component2 = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <p className = "component2">This is Component2</p>
    )
  }
});

var Button2 = React.createClass({
  previous: function(){
    ReactDOM.render(<Block1/>, document.getElementById("container"));
  },

  render: function(){
    return(
      <button className = "button1"  onClick = {this.previous}>previous</button>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Block1/>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: You should render a single component at the top, and then create a state machine to decide which step to render and when to render it. It sounds like you want to make a wizard.

Comment: create a JSfiddle with this code and i'll help edit.

Comment: @BlairAnderson here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/theWhiteWhale/guq81pa9/)

Comment: I answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37467120/1536309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the components inside `<Block1>` only on button click?

Yes.

One way to approach this is to have the main top component `<Block1>`, or let's call it `<MainBlock>`, be a stateful component that maintains the state and drives the logic that determines what gets rendered. Other components could probably just be stateless representation components that are rendered depending on the state flag set by `<MainBlock>`.

Essentially, `<MainBlock>` has a state flag, let's say `isShowingNext`, that it uses to determine which section ("next" or "previous") gets rendered, and the flag gets set by actions called from the buttons.

As far as the buttons themselves, they have onClick listeners attached that, whenever clicked, call an action in the `<MainBlock>` and `<MainBlock>` updates the state flag and re-renders the proper component.

Since the buttons are almost identical, we can combine them into a single button component, for example `<ToggleButton>`, that will conditionally render (either "previous" or "next") depending on the passed flag (see **First Approach**).

Depending on your use-case, if the buttons (and their rendering logic) are not that similar, you can have two of them, for example `<ButtonPrev>` and `<ButtonNext>`, where one or the other gets rendered by the `<MainBlock>` depending on the state flag (see **Second Approach**).

#### First Approach

[**jsFiddle sample**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/43515/)

```
var MainBlock = React.createClass({

  // initially we are showing the "previous" page
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      isShowingNext: false
    };
  },

  // action that updates the state flag to determine what gets rendered
  handleUpdateIsShowingNext: function(isShowingNext) {
    this.setState({
      isShowingNext: isShowingNext
    });
  },

  // render function that displays the proper template based on the state flag
  render: function(){
    var isShowingNext = this.state.isShowingNext;
    return (
      <div className="block">
        {isShowingNext ? <ComponentNext/> : <ComponentPrev/>}
        <ToggleButton  isShowingNext={isShowingNext}
                        onUpdateIsShowingNext={this.handleUpdateIsShowingNext}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

// button for that toggles between "previous" or "next" page depending on the logic
var ToggleButton = React.createClass({
  toggle: function(){
    this.props.onUpdateIsShowingNext(!this.props.isShowingNext); // toggle the "isShowingNext" flag
  },

  render: function(){
    var isShowingNext = this.props.isShowingNext;
    if (isShowingNext) {
        return <button className="button-prev" onClick={this.toggle}>Prev</button>;
    } else {
        return <button className="button-next" onClick={this.toggle}>Next</button>;
    }
  }
});

// representational component for the "previous" page
var ComponentPrev = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <p className = "component-prev">This is ComponentPrev</p>;
  }
});

// representational component for the "next" page
var ComponentNext = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <p className = "component-next">This is ComponentNext</p>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MainBlock/>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

#### Second Approach

[**jsFiddle sample**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/43517/)

```
var MainBlock = React.createClass({

  // initially we are showing the "previous" page
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      isShowingNext: false
    };
  },

  // returns the template for the "previous" page
  getTemplateForPrev: function() {
    return (
      <div className="block">
        <ComponentPrev/>
        <ButtonPrev onUpdateIsShowingNext={this.handleUpdateIsShowingNext}/>
      </div>
    );
  },

  // returns the template for the "next" page
  getTemplateForNext: function() {
    return (
      <div className="block">
        <ComponentNext/>
        <ButtonNext onUpdateIsShowingNext={this.handleUpdateIsShowingNext}/>
      </div>
    );
  },

  // action that updates the state flag to determine what gets rendered
  handleUpdateIsShowingNext: function(isShowingNext) {
    this.setState({
      isShowingNext: isShowingNext
    });
  },

  // render function that displays the proper template based on the state flag
  render: function(){
    return this.state.isShowingNext ? this.getTemplateForNext() : this.getTemplateForPrev();
  }
});

// representational component for the "previous" page
var ComponentPrev = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <p className = "component-prev">This is ComponentPrev</p>;
  }
});

// button for the "previous" page
var ButtonPrev = React.createClass({
  next: function(){
    this.props.onUpdateIsShowingNext(true); // clicking "previous" makes isShowingNext be true
  },

  render: function(){
    return <button className="button-prev" onClick={this.next}>Next</button>;
  }
});

// representational component for the "next" page
var ComponentNext = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <p className = "component-next">This is ComponentNext</p>;
  }
});

// button for the "next" page
var ButtonNext = React.createClass({
  previous: function(){
    this.props.onUpdateIsShowingNext(false); // clicking "previous" makes isShowingNext be false
  },

  render: function(){
    return <button className="button-next"  onClick={this.previous}>previous</button>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MainBlock/>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't want to use `ReactDOM.render` anywhere else inside your component structure.

It looks like you're going down the route of creating a "wizard" with a few different steps.

I edited your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guq81pa9/1/

Top Level component keeps track of which 'step' you're on, and handles toggling back and forth:

```
var Block = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      step: 1
    }
  },
  goto: function(step){
    this.setState({
      step: step || 1 // default to step 1
    })
  },
  render: function(){
    var renderStep =  <div className="block component1">
        <Component1/>
        <Button onClick={this.goto.bind(this,2)}>Next</Button>
      </div>

    if (this.state.step === 2) {
      renderStep =  <div className="block component2">
        <Component2/>
        <Button onClick={this.goto.bind(this,1)}>Previous</Button>
      </div>
    }

    return renderStep
  }
});
```